# What to use with WP8, SQL Compact Edition or Sqlite?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sqlite, windows-phone-8

I am new to WP8(and to .net as well). What should I choose to work in WP8, SQL CE or Sqlite?

Secondly, if I choose Sqlite, it is possible (and should I use) LINQ?

I have gone thorough many link, but didn't got exact answer.

I started trying few samples using Sqlite (Nuget project), and found using Sqlite, I need not to use Create/Delete kind of queries, it will also help for insert. So should I use LINQ instead of these features?

@Edit: Added sample code to illustrate my point
Sample Code

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public int UnitsInStock { get; set; }
}

private void DbInterLinq()
{   
SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH);
conn.CreateTable<Product>();

InsertSampleinDB(conn);
GetDataFromDb(conn);
}
```

Now in code, I am able to insert data in db, now I want to use select queries, which will get only Product with product names greater than 10 chars.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this will help you.Here is the query to get only products with a name longer than 10 chars from a collection of products:

```
 private void SelectFromDb()
    {   
    SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH);
    //conn.CreateTable<Product>();
    //InsertSampleinDB(conn);
    List<Product> myProducts = conn.Table<Product>().ToList().Where(x => x.Name.Length > 10);
    }
```

Comment: +1: I am ok with solution, but I have little problem, when you say conn.Table<Product>(), you are actually fetching all the data from db, can we not only get only required data from db?

Comment: @pranitkothari yes you can do it. List<Product> myProducts = conn.CreateCommand("Your select command ").ExecuteQuery<Product>().ToList();

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're meaning with [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINQ) is actually the use of the [Entity Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_framework). LINQ is simply an approach to write conditions and loops in a compressed query style. You are able to use it everywhere in your code, it's not bound to your database engine at all.

The EntityFramework allows you to create actual objects from your database. Now whenever you add or delete one of those objects at runtime, this change gets reflected in your database, so you want have to take care of any SQL strings.

You can easily work with SQLite and the Entity Framework, there are some good tutorials out there, as always, google is your friend. And since it's a supported feature of the .net framework, it should work like a charm on WP8.

To get only products with a name longer than 10 chars from a collection of products:

```
List<Product> myProducts = ProductList.Where(x => x.Name.Length > 10);
```

Comment: I have edited my question with code, so it is more clear now.